# Is this Firebase security setting safe?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

If the security rule is written as above, even if the database url is shared, other people cannot access it without permission, such as reading or writing, unless hackers hack it dangerously, and is it safe? And do you recommend this way?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?  The rule is rejecting all end user access from the web and mobile SDKs.  If that's what you want, then leave it.  You will only be able to modify the database with administrative credentials using a service account.  We can't make a recommendation about this setting, because we don't know what your security requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

#### Yes that is safe

I have to admit it doesn't seem very useful!

Perhaps you are going to access the database from a Firebase Function, which can have admin access to everything (disregarding rules).

For example, you might have all user interaction with the database being indirect.

- User wants some data from the database
- App calls a Firebase function
- Function returns answer to app
- App displays it

Similarly

- User updates some data in the app
- App calls a Firebase Function
- Function updates the app

In that case, this approach might be work. However, it does seem to slightly defeat the point of a realtime database.

Comment: So you're saying that if you do that with the security rules, you can show the database url to others?

Comment: Yes. They won't be able to read or write to it.